# What is the relation between spatial velocity and temporal velocity?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, velocity

Let me define spatial velocity as the velocity at which an object moves through space (just velocity as we all know) and Temporal velocity as the velocity through which it moves through time.

When spatial velocity increases, Temporal velocity decreases.

What is the relation connecting these two quantities?

I think it involves the constant c and some square terms.

I expect a term like
$v^2-t^2=c^2$

where s is spatial velocity,
t temporal velocity
and c ,the speed of light

**Update 1** : I found it  $$v^2+(ct)^2 = c^2$$ where v-spatial velocity,
t- temporal velocity,
c-speed of light

Note:Here I have take temporal velocity $t = \frac{dt}{dt'}$.

Let me explain why.

Imagine a space ship traveling at a velocity v.
There is a laser at the bottom of the ship which emits a photon that bounces back from a mirror at the top of the ship. If the time interval needed for the photon to bounce back as observed by a person on earth  the time interval of a process as observed by the earth is dt and the time interval required for the same process to happen, as observed by the space traveller is dt' ,

Then, $$dt' = \frac{dt}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}} \
\hspace{20mm}            
\rightarrow(1)$$

One might be inclined to take the temporal velocity as dt'/dt.
But if we take so, then  dt' is greater than dt implies  the temporal velocity is greater than one.
But if dt' is greater dt that means time is running slowly in the spaceship.
So, by that convection , if time runs slower, Temporal velocity is higher.
Clearly this is not a good convection.
So we can take temporal velocity as $\frac{dt}{dt'}$.
This checks well with our intuitive understanding of temporal velocity and can be considered as a good definition.
So, by this definition and using eqn (1),

$$v^2+(ct)^2=c^2$$

This makes sense, because if an object moves at the speed of light, v=c
so $$c^2+(ct)^2=c^2$$  $$\implies t=0$$
as expected because if an object travels at the speed of light, then its temporal velocity is zero.

So, then I thought It would make more sense to define temporal velocity as ct to make the equation look like
$$v^2+t^2=c^2$$

[image]

This means that when an object remains stationary w.r.t us, its spatial velocity is zero and temporal velocity is c. It does not move through space but moves through time at the maximum speed.

Contrary to this, when spatial velocity = c ,then t=0. Which means when an object moves through space at the maximum speed, it can't move through time.

Notice how the sum of the square of spatial velocity and temporal velocity is a constant.

So we are always moving through the spacetime at a constant velocity c.
sometimes the spatial component is higher than temporal component and sometimes the temporal component is greater than spatial component.

One way or the other, the total velocity is same

But then the unit for temporal velocity becomes $m/s^2$
So can I do that?

Can I define temporal velocity as ct?

Comment: It sounds as if you are talking about the [four velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-velocity).

Comment: Concerning your update to the original question: There is an already established formulation of special relativity, supported by a vast amount of experimental evidence. Although your proposed definitions do not use standard terminology, you can try to attempt to use your constructions in the existing formulation of special relativity to see if your constructions are consistent with special relativity and its experimental support.

Comment: I updated my answer in response to your update.

Comment: can you please not call temporal velocity $t$? $t$ is usually reserved for time, as indicated by your own use of symbol $dt$. It is confusing. Can't you call it $v_t$ or something? Also $ct$ has units of $m/s$ since $t=dt/dt'$ is dimensionless.

Comment: You can also ask a question about how your personal four-velocity compares with the usual four-velocity that we use in special relativity. You can ask about the drawbacks that your definition would have.

Comment: @Umaxo yes, what about $\tau$ ?

Comment: 2. Yeah ct has dmensions of m/s . That is why I asked  if we can can define temporal velocity that way.

Answer (score 7):

My UPDATE to this answer is at the end, in response to your updated question.

---

(My answer tries to use standard terminology, which might help clarify your question. It also fills in more details than you might have wanted. But I do so because there may be related misconceptions.)

The components of the "4-velocity" vector $\tilde V$ (a unit-timelike vector in spacetime)
are
$$\tilde V=(V_t)\hat t +(V_x)\hat x,$$
where
$V_t^2- V_x^2 =1$. This applies only to massive particles.

In terms of rapidity $\theta$, where the "spatial velocity" $v=c\tanh\theta$,
we have
$$\tilde V=(\cosh\theta)\hat t +(\sinh\theta)\hat x.$$

- The "temporal component of the 4-velocity" is $V_t=\cosh\theta=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(v/c)^2}}=\gamma=\mbox{time dilation factor}$.
- The "spatial component of the 4-velocity" is $V_x=\sinh\theta=\frac{(v/c)}{\sqrt{1-(v/c)^2}}=\displaystyle\frac{v}{c}\gamma=\mbox{"dimensionless proper-velocity"}=\mbox{"dimensionless celerity"}$.
  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_velocity (proper-velocity is not a good term. Celerity is better.)
- The ratio of these components is $\displaystyle\frac{V_x}{V_t}=\tanh\theta=\displaystyle\frac{v}{c}
  =\mbox{"dimensionless spatial velocity"}$.
  This $v$ is the usual "velocity in space" (whose magnitude is always less than $c$ for massive particles)

**Note that the usual "spatial velocity [through space]"

is not the same thing as the spatial-component of the 4-velocity [through spacetime].**

---

[image: robphy-4velocity]

from my post at
https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/velocity-through-spacetime.957038/post-6068213

---

So, multiplying the 4-velocity by $c$ to give it dimensions of speed,
$$c\tilde V=(cV_t)\hat t +(cV_x)\hat x,$$
the temporal component is $c\gamma$,
the spatial component is $v\gamma=\mbox{"proper velocity"}=\mbox{"celerity"}$,
the ratio of components is $(v/c)$, 
where
$v=\mbox{"spatial velocity"}$ [the usual velocity in space]

... of the massive particle.

In terms of $\gamma$,
we have
$$c\tilde V=(\gamma c)\hat t +(\gamma v)\hat x.$$
Note that
$$(\gamma c)^2-(\gamma v)^2=\gamma^2(c^2-v^2)=\gamma^2 c^2(1-(v/c)^2)=c^2$$

This $c\tilde V$ could be thought of as the "momentum 4-vector divided by the mass of the massive particle": $\displaystyle\frac{mc\tilde V}{m}=\frac{\tilde P}{m}$

(It does not apply to light.)

---

**UPDATE**

Your updated question reminds me of an old calculation of mine
that seems related to your line of questioning.

I will reproduce parts of it here because the original version (at
https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/speed-of-light.75111/#post-565681 )
looks like it has some formatting issues.

> Here's my $\$0.02$ on the "speed through time" and "speed through spacetime" idea (based on my understanding of the transciption of a small passage from the Elegant Universe)....
>
> To me, **"speed through spacetime"** means the "spacetime-norm of an object's 4-velocity". In relativity, the 4-velocity of an observer is the unit tangent-vector to the observer's worldline. In the attached diagram, it is the Minkowski-unit vectors $\hat t$ and $\hat u$ shown.
>
> Since, by convention, time is measured in seconds and space in meters, one has to multiply the time-components by a speed, (say) "the speed of light" [that is, the spatial-speed of a light ray], in order to work with spacetime components with homogeneous units. Any speed could have been used to make the units homogeneous. In special relativity, it is convenient to use the "speed of light" to avoid the nuisance of carrying around a dimensionless factor.
>
> Now here are some reasons why emphasizing the "speed through spacetime" idea doesn't seem that useful to me.
>
> [As someone must have mentioned before] In special relativity, the "speed through spacetime" of a light ray is ZERO... since light rays have lightlike or "null" tangent-vectors. While certainly true, I wonder if this might be more confusing to a beginner.
>
> Secondly, if one were to formulate a spacetime geometry for Galilean Relativity, one would also normalize 4-velocities as described above. To work with homogeneous units, one would still have to use a speed. Of course, the speed of light wouldn't be anything special in Galilean Relativity. But let's use it (or, if you wish, any other speed playing the role of a conversion unit). One would still say that all observers travel with that same "speed through spacetime". So, the phrase seems rather empty...except to say that "an observer's 4-velocity is a unit vector (in the appropriate spacetime geometry)".
>
> Now, concerning **"speed through time"**...
>
> If **"speed through space"** is $\displaystyle\frac{dx}{dt}$
> (the rate of change of the object's-spatial-displacement with respect to the object's-time-displacement,
> $\displaystyle\frac{(PA)}{(AO)}=\frac{\sinh\theta}{\cosh\theta}=\tanh\theta,$
>
> where $\theta$ is the rapidity),
>
> then, by analogy, **"speed through time"** is
> $\displaystyle \frac{dt}{dt}$
> (the rate of change of the object's-time-displacement with respect to the object's-time-displacement,
> $\displaystyle\frac{(AO)}{(AO)}=1$).
>
> Thus, it would seem inappropriate to use **"speed through time"** to mean
> $\displaystyle \frac{d\tau}{dt}$
> (the rate of change of the object's-proper-time-displacement with respect to the object's-time-displacement,
> $\displaystyle\frac{(PO)}{(AO)}=\frac{1}{\gamma}=\frac{1}{\cosh\theta}$
> ).
>
> **"speed through proper-time"** might be more appropriate.
>
> [image: robphy-physicsforums]
>
> Finally, it might be interesting to express the following relations in terms of the rapidity $\theta$:
> \begin{align*}
> c^2\left(dt/d\tau\right)^2 - \left(d\vec{x}/d\tau\right)^2 &= c^2\\
> c^2\left(\displaystyle\frac{(AO)}{(PO)}\right)^2 - \left(c\displaystyle\frac{(PA)}{(PO)}\right)^2 &=\\
> c^2(\cosh\theta)^2 - c^2(\sinh\theta)^2 &=\\
> \end{align*}
> and
> \begin{align*}
> c^2\left(d\tau/dt\right)^2 + \left(d\vec{x}/dt\right)^2 &= c^2\\
> c^2\left(\displaystyle\frac{(PO)}{(AO)}\right)^2 + \left(c\displaystyle\frac{(PA)}{(AO)}\right)^2 &=\\
> c^2\left(\displaystyle\frac{1}{\cosh\theta}\right)^2 + c^2(\tanh\theta)^2 &=\\
> c^2\left(\displaystyle\frac{1}{\cosh\theta}\right)^2 + 
> c^2\left(\displaystyle\frac{\sinh\theta}{\cosh\theta}\right)^2 &=\\
> c^2\left(\displaystyle\frac{1+\sinh^2\theta}{\cosh^2\theta}\right) &=
> \end{align*}
>
> Note:
> In the first expression, it's the usual difference of the square-norms of the Minkowski-perpendicular legs of this triangle. (The signature of the metric is evident here.)
>
> In the second expression (which may appear to look Euclidean at first glance), it is effectively the sum of the square-norms of
> the
> $\color{red}{\mbox{timelike-hypotenuse (PO)}}$ and
> the
> $\color{blue}{\mbox{spacelike-leg (PA)}}$.
> Note carefully that
> $\color{red}{\mbox{(PO)}}$ is not Minkowski-perpendicular to $\color{blue}{\mbox{(PA)}}$.
>
> In summary, the mathematics is, of course, correct.
> However, the emphasis on "speed through spacetime" seems empty,
> and the use of "speed through time" seems inappropriate since it involves the proper-time of the object along (OP).
>
> Maybe I should get myself a copy of the Elegant Universe to see this passage for myself... in case I've misunderstood the transcription.

Comment: >>In special relativity, the "speed through spacetime" of a light ray is ZERO..>> Could you explain how? I thought that the spatial velocity of light is c and temporal velocity is 0, so the spacetime velocity is c.

Comment: >> the mathematics is, of course, correct. However, the emphasis on "speed through spacetime" seems empty>>But The invariance of spacetime velocity explains why we can't go faster than the speed of light

Comment: Because we always move at the speed of light through spacetime. When we accelerate , we are just converting more and more of our temporal velocity to spatial velocity.When we reach the speed of light, all our temporal velocity is converted to spacial velocity so there is none left to convert to ..Here is a video I found on youtube that talks about this exact thing :https://youtu.be/au0QJYISe4c?t=85

Comment: When i said >>when WE accelerate,WE are just converting...>>This is respect to some other observer or some other reference frame which is not attached to us. Ofcourse, we cannot move or accelerate with respect to ourself.

Comment: In a position-vs-time-graph, the slope of the motion of the particle is the spatial velocity. In relativity, the 4-velocity of a massive-particle is a unit-vector in the position-vs-time graph.. and these tips lie on a hyperbola with asymptotes corresponding to the speed of light. The corresponding "4-velocity" cannot be defined because a unit-vector cannot be defined due to the fact that light-signals have zero [rest] mass. Thus, we say that light-signals are "null".  These are more-or-less the official mathematically defined definitions.

Comment: The video you referenced, in my opinion, is not helpful in really learning the subject because there are misconceptions that I tried to address in my updated answer. Part of the problem of such videos is that real definitions are not given, just verbal definitions that conflate two or more ideas. Some such approaches are based on the real definitions.... but, in my opinion, not enough detail is provided to avoid misconceptions.

Comment: I am not familiar with 4-velocity(Have not studied it yet). But with this convention, the velocity of light through spacetime is not zero. In fact the velocity of every object through spacetime is zero. Isnt it more beutiful and brings uniformity to the nature?

Comment: Yeah , I agree that the video is not detailed and does not provide any real definition for temporal velocity.But that is why I gave the definition in my updated answer

Comment: Hey, and i also derived the circle equation    ($x^2+\tau^2 = c^2$)from that definition.

Comment: You can learn "conventions" that seem to work in certain circumstances. Or you can learn the definitions that seem to be clear, consistent, and lead to measurable predictions that are confirmed by experiment. In my learning of the subject, I have found "pop books" have inspired my interest to learn the real definitions of things... and thus learn from physics textbooks written by relativists.

Comment: Having not learned relativity thoroughly is my weakness, I agree.  But I have learned enough so that there are no misconceptions.If I have learned it , I may be not able to come up with this equation.

Comment: This is making me think whether the fact that young scientists tend to make more groundbreaking discoveries because they have  fresh perspective. For example take Einstein, most of his groundbreaking papers were written when he was very young

Comment: This may be because they are not very familiar to   "definitions that seem to be clear, consistent, and lead to measurable predictions that are confirmed by experiment"

Comment: "Take a fresh perspective.  Look from a different angle. Let go of traditional conventions if what stands before you is a better and bright future." Just being poetic, Dont take it seriously :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127020/discussion-between-abhinav-p-b-and-robphy).

Answer (score 1):

@robphy has given a nice and detailed answer, and it's well worth reading and considering. I'm going to throw in a slightly different take on things, namely that you should specify exactly what you mean by "temporal velocity". Generally speaking, spatial velocity of a clock moving with respect to an observer (we consider the observer to be "at rest") along the x-axis is defined as $\frac{dx}{dt}$, where $x$ and $t$ are as measured by the observer. But then what is "temporal velocity"? The obvious analog is $\frac{dt}{dt}$, but this is always 1 and so isn't interesting. Another possibility is $\frac{dt'}{dt}$, where $t'$ is the time as measured by the moving clock. That's a reasonable choice, but note that the original "spatial velocity" used only the observer's coordinates, whereas this uses a mixture of coordinates.

In some sense by comparing $\frac{dx}{dt}$ and $\frac{dt'}{dt}$ we're mixing apples and oranges.
The spatial analog of $\frac{dt'}{dt}$ is $\frac{dx'}{dt}$, but that's *not* the same as the original definition of spatial velocity.

Comment: If you think about it, $\frac{dt}{dt'}$ is a better definition for spacial velocity.Then, $$v^2 + (ct)^2 = c^2$$ where v is the spacial velocity and t the temporal velocity.

Comment: See my edited question for more details.

Comment: @AbhinavPB Does your "better" definition agree with experiment? and if so, is it useful? See my comment to your update to your question.

Comment: @robphy definition is definition, what does it have to do with experiments? The question is only whether the definition is useful, not whether it agrees with experiment. It is laws that needs to agree with experiment, definition says nothing about real world. E.g. we can define force by $\vec{F}=\sqrt{m\dot{\left|\vec{a}\right|}}\vec{a}$ and no one can prevent us. We measure $m$ and $\vec{a}$ and compute $\vec{F}.$ The problem is, stating laws in terms of this $\vec{F}$ would be a pain.

Answer (score 0):

Velocity is all about a ratio: a ratio between a spatial distance and an elapsed time. If you want to consider some other ratio, such as the ratio between time difference on one clock and time difference on another, then I think it would be better not to call this other ratio a 'velocity', but you could call it a 'rate'.

Returning to velocity (i.e. ratio of distance and time), there is relative velocity and another type sometimes called closing velocity which I don't need to get into. The main thing is that if the trajectory in spacetime is a line, then velocity is about the slope of this line. To be precise, it is about the slope of one such line compared to another. But for a given pair of lines there is just one angle between them. So I don't think it is helpful terminology to talk about two velocities (one spatial and one temporal). Rather, there is a single size of the relative velocity between any two worldlines at any given event. The relative velocity is the ratio of the distance over time as one of them moves in the rest frame of the other.

Finally, I think your question is aimed at getting a feel for the way proper time along a worldline increments more and more slowly, compared to time in some inertial frame, as the worldline approaches the speed of light relative to that frame. I would recommend you focus your thinking around the notions of *invariant* and the related notion of time dilation. By *invariant* I mean the fact that the combination
$$
c^2 \Delta t^2 - \Delta x^2
$$
has the same value no matter what frame is used to determine the distance $\Delta x$ and the time $\Delta t$ between two given events. That is the thing you want to get your head around, by a plethora of examples of what it tells you about space, time and motion.